# Should unneeded provocative content be removed from answers

Tags: discussion

A couple of flags have been raised [on this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/95065/929) that suggests that the OP's example title is not appropriate. I have edited the title which I think conveys the same information, but in a more appropriate way. The OP has rolled my revision back.

Which way do we want the answer?

Answer (score 16):

I think the original title overestimates the universality of the author's sense of humour, and is in a certain technical sense gratuitous. If the same point can be made with a title that does not risk either causing offence or derailing, then why go for a title that does have such risks, unless one is desperate to burnish one's Lenny Bruce credentials?

Comment: @LeonMeier You were using a lurid title, which arguably cheapens actual real-world events by referring to them in a monumentally shallow and glib fashion, and one which suggests you have not actually thought seriously about the context & specifics of the events you refer to. Either you are arguing in bad faith, or you lack the wit to imagine who you _might_ be offending; either way, as a result of your comment, I am not inclined to any further discussion with you on this.

Answer (score 9):

As with @YemonChoi, I found the title to be entirely unnecessary, and a distraction from the content of the answer itself. While I'm all for humorous example titles, it's trivial to make one *not* involving an inflammatory topic.

When it comes down to it, I don't think the fake title added anything, *did* feel like it was baiting a bit, and I was entirely comfortable with its removal. The further edits by the OP don't do much to make me think I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the question [Who has the final authority in an edit war? OP or a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291153/217406) on Meta Stack Exchange

and one of the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292796/217406) says

> What is a moderator? Someone who is trusted to know the site rules and enforce them. Either elected by the site users themselves, or by Stack Exchange staff (or SE staff member on their own), a moderator has the final say in everything, and got tools to enforce their decisions

Comment: @LeonMeier if you didn't like my edit, you could have changed it. I thought the reason for the edit was pretty obvious, but apparently you may not have understood the reason. I invited you to ask on meta/chat and you declined. As it escalated, I brought it here.

Comment: @scaahu no question mods have final authority, but I wanted to make sure I was interpreting what the community wanted. From the voting, it seems like I did.

Comment: @StrongBad My answer was aiming to Leon, not you. The comment space under his answer (now deleted) was cluttered, so I used the answer space to let him know that please respect the Mod's decision. However, I would like to say something about this issue. If I were the mod, I would delete his answer when I received abusive/offensive flags.